# StandAlone DroolsApplication is working fine but same application is not working when bundle with my product

Tags: java, drools, drools-kie-server

I AM USING 6.2.0 FINAL .I have created the droolengine as a standalone application .It is working fine as expected and all rules are being fired which are present in the DRL file. But same application was integrated with my Product, but here rules are not being fired which are present the DRL  file.

**Now here i post my DRL file too below**

```
package com.myorg.rules;


import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.password.droolsengine.ValidatePasswordWorkflowData;
global java.lang.Integer noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive;
global java.lang.Integer noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated;
global java.lang.String NoOfIdentifierstobecosecutiveErrorCode;
global java.lang.String noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeatedErrorCode;
global java.lang.String NoOfIdentifierstobecosecutiveCustomeMsg;
global java.lang.String noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeatedCustomMsg;
global java.lang.Boolean ValidPassword;

rule "CONSECUTIVEANDSAMEIDENTIFIER"

    when
        validatePasswordWorkflowData : ValidatePasswordWorkflowData(passwordFromEB:password)
    then
         noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive=4;
         noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated=4;

         System.out.println("starting of then ");



  validatePasswordWorkflowData.setValidatePasswordWorkflowData(ConsecutiveAndSameIdentifierRepetationValidation(passwordFromEB,noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive,noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated));
     System.out.println("ending of then ");  
 end

function ValidatePasswordWorkflowData ConsecutiveAndSameIdentifierRepetationValidation(String password,
            int noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive, int noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated)

    {   

     System.out.println("starting of ConsecutiveAndSameIdentifierRepetationValidation method ");
     boolean ValidPassword=true;
           String NoOfIdentifierstobecosecutiveErrorCode="LV00302";
           String noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeatedErrorCode="LV00303";
           String NoOfIdentifierstobecosecutiveCustomeMsg="password must not contain , at a time   consecutive identifiers   more than ";
           String noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeatedCustomMsg="and no of same identifier repetition should no grater than";


    ValidatePasswordWorkflowData validatePassword=new ValidatePasswordWorkflowData();

        /*
         * 
   LV00301=Error during Password Validation. Reason {0}
   LV00302=Error during Password Validation. Reason password must not contain , at a time   consecutive identifiers more than 
   LV00303=Error during Password Validation. Reason password must not contain,at a time,  no of same identifier repetition should no greter than   
           **/

        StringBuilder conscutiveIndentifierRegex = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sameIndentifierRegex = new StringBuilder();

        Pattern ConsecutiveIdentifierRegex = Pattern.compile(
                buildRegex(conscutiveIndentifierRegex, noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Pattern sameidentifierRepeatRegex = Pattern.compile(
                buildRegexRepeatedString(sameIndentifierRegex, noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated),
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        conscutiveIndentifierRegex.setLength(0);
        sameIndentifierRegex.setLength(0);

        Matcher ConsecutiveIdentifierRegexMatcher = ConsecutiveIdentifierRegex.matcher(password);

        Matcher sameidentifierRepeatRegexMatcher = sameidentifierRepeatRegex.matcher(password);

        if(ConsecutiveIdentifierRegexMatcher.find())
            {   if(noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive==3)
                validatePassword.setErrorCode(NoOfIdentifierstobecosecutiveErrorCode);
            else
                validatePassword.setCustomErrorMessage(NoOfIdentifierstobecosecutiveCustomeMsg+" "+noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive +noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeatedCustomMsg+" "+noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated);
            }

             if( (sameidentifierRepeatRegexMatcher.find()))
            {

                if(noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated==3)

                validatePassword.setErrorCode(noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeatedErrorCode);
                else if(noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated!=3)
                    validatePassword.setCustomErrorMessage(NoOfIdentifierstobecosecutiveCustomeMsg+" "+noOfIdentifierstobecosecutive +""+noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeatedCustomMsg+" "+noOfSameIdentifierToBeRepeated);
        }
            else if(validatePassword.getErrorCode()==null && validatePassword.getCustomErrorMessage()==null)
                   validatePassword.setValidPassword(ValidPassword);

        System.out.println("ending of ConsecutiveAndSameIdentifierRepetationValidation method ");
return validatePassword;
    }

    function String buildRegex(StringBuilder sb, int seqStart) {
        for (int i = seqStart; i <= seqStart; i++) {
            buildRegexCharGroup(sb, i, '0', '9');
            // buildRegexCharGroup(sb, i, 'A', 'Z');
            buildRegexCharGroup(sb, i, 'a', 'z');
            // buildRegexRepeatedString(sb, i);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    function void buildRegexCharGroup(StringBuilder sb, int seqLength, char start, char end) {
        for (char c = start; c <= end - seqLength + 1; c++) {
            char ch = c;
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                sb.append('|');
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < seqLength; i++) {
                sb.append(ch++);
            }
        }
    }

    function String buildRegexRepeatedString(StringBuilder sb, int seqLength) {
        // sb.append('|');
        sb.append("([a-z\\d])");
        for (int i = 1; i < seqLength; i++) {
            sb.append("\\1");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

**My Java class which is consuming the DRL File Here Below
========================================================**

```
package com.password.droolsengine;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.kie.api.KieBase;
import org.kie.api.KieBaseConfiguration;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.Message;
import org.kie.api.io.ResourceType;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

public class PasswordValidatorEngine {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {

        ValidatePasswordWorkflowData passwordWorkflowData = new ValidatePasswordWorkflowData();
        passwordWorkflowData.setPassword("1234551157813151");
        String st = executeStatefull(passwordWorkflowData, "src/main/resources/Myorg/drl/Myorg.drl");


    }

    public static String executeStatefull(ValidatePasswordWorkflowData passwordWorkflowData, String drlFilePath) {

        String error = "";

        try {
            KieSession kieSession = null;
            String content = readFile(new File(drlFilePath));
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            String inMemoryDrlFileName = "src/main/resources/stateFuSesramamasionRule.drl";
            KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

            kfs.write(inMemoryDrlFileName,
                    ks.getResources().newReaderResource(new FileReader(drlFilePath)).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL));

            KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
            if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
                System.out.println(kieBuilder.getResults().toString());
            }
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
            KieBaseConfiguration kbconf = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
            KieBase kbase = kContainer.newKieBase(kbconf);
            kieSession = kbase.newKieSession();

            kieSession.insert(passwordWorkflowData);
            kieSession.fireAllRules();

            ValidatePasswordWorkflowData validatePasswordWorkflowData = passwordWorkflowData
                    .getValidatePasswordWorkflowData();

            System.out.println("custom_msg " + validatePasswordWorkflowData.getCustomErrorMessage());
            System.out.println("error_code" + validatePasswordWorkflowData.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println(validatePasswordWorkflowData.isValidPassword());

            kieSession.dispose();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return error;
    }

    private static String readFile(File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append(ls);
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**ValidatePasswordWorkflowData  IS THE POJO CLASS THROUGH WHICH WE ARE GIVING INPUT TO DRL FILE AND AFTER PEROCCESSING DRL FILE ,THIS POJO WILL BE SET RESULT .
  ValidatePasswordWorkflowData  POJO IS BELOW**

```
package com.password.droolsengine;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidatePasswordWorkflowData {

    private String password = null;

    private boolean isValidPassword = false;

    private String errorCode = null;



    private String customErrorMessage = null;

    private ValidatePasswordWorkflowData validatePasswordWorkflowData = null;

    public ValidatePasswordWorkflowData getValidatePasswordWorkflowData() {
        System.out.println("getter method");
        return validatePasswordWorkflowData;

    }

    public void setValidatePasswordWorkflowData(ValidatePasswordWorkflowData passwordWorkflowData) {
        validatePasswordWorkflowData = passwordWorkflowData;
        System.out.println("setter method");
    }

    public String getCustomErrorMessage() {
        return customErrorMessage;
    }

    public void setCustomErrorMessage(String customErrorMessage) {
        this.customErrorMessage = customErrorMessage;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isValidPassword() {
        return isValidPassword;
    }

    public void setValidPassword(boolean isValidPassword) {
        this.isValidPassword = isValidPassword;
    }

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }



}
```

**below jars i added in the path**

```
    drools-compiler-6.2.0.Final.jar
kie-internal-6.2.0.Final.jar
antlr-runtime-3.5.jar
ecj-4.3.1.jar
mvel2-2.2.4.Final.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
drools-core-6.2.0.Final.jar
drools-decisiontables-6.2.0.Final.jar
drools-templates-6.2.0.Final.jar
poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-3.10.1.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
kie-api-6.2.0.Final.jar
xstream-1.4.10.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
```

**Below  Pom.xml i have used to created application ..same depedencies i have used while bundling my application with my Product**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.peogrammertech</groupId>
    <artifactId>droolsCache</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: Any exceptions? Logging, you can compare? Are you sure the development path "src/main/resources" is available at runtime?

Comment: @Arnaud..Hi Arnaud....I am not getting any errors .  DroolEngine is not firing my rule in DRL when it is bundled with my product .But same application working fine as a standalone application with same DRL file . I OBSERVED that in standalone application,when i debug  Session.FireAllRules() ,its giving Agenda but its not giving in the case when i bundle with my product

Comment: @Arnaud  am not undersatnding why it is working as standalone application  fine and rule wriiten in DRL file is fired .  But same application is not working  when i bundle with My product ...please some body give resolution for this ...

Comment: I have followed this link to create my Application  http://programmertech.com/program/jee/drools-dynamic-rule-loading-from-string

Comment: that "src/main/resources" is extremely suspicious. If you are using Maven, then whatever you have under "src/main/resources" is going to be present at the root level of the classpath. Could you include in your question how is your code structured (where do you have your java classes and where do you have your resources) and how are you running it?

Comment: @Frito..Hi ...src/main/resources is the path for my DRL file when i am running my application as a standalone application . /apps/myproject/DRL_Files/SOME_DRL_File/myfile.drl"; is the path of my DRL file when i bundle application with my produc

Comment: @Esteban Aliverti ..Hi Thanks for reply ..src/main/resources is being used in the standalone application . but i when created same standlone application in my product as part of one new package, its not working .here src/main/resources is not being used .to keep DRL file , i used this path only ../apps/myproject/DRL_Files/SOME_DRL_File/myfile.drl"

Comment: Is there anybody who know drools ?